# lasso coefficients larger than 1

Tags: multiple-regression, lasso, glmnet

I am comparing lasso implementation in *liblinear* and *glmnet* and I can see one of the coefficients from  *liblinear* fit is larger than 1 , while for the same data set, glmnet coefficients are all between -1 and 1.

Since the data is normalized, I was curious if coefficients in these models can be outside the range of [-1, 1] and if not, does it mean something is wrong ? e.g the optimization has not converged ?

I appreciate more insight,

Answer (score 1):

Standardizing or normalizing predictors doesn't affect the range of the coefficients, which in linear regression and most of its descendants (such as the lasso) is always $(-∞, ∞)$. You're confusing the range of the predictors with the range of the coefficients.